# Compile-time error: No known instance method for selector 'setDetailItem:'

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, selector

In Xcode 5.0.2 I create a blank Detail-Master app for iPhone.

Then in Main.storyboard I replace the UILabel by a UIWebView and declare it as `webView` in the [DetailViewController.h](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/MyAuth/MyAuth/DetailViewController.h).

Also I replace `id *defaultItem` by `NSDictionary *dict`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *dict;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@end
```

In the [MasterViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/MyAuth/MyAuth/MasterViewController.m) I hardcode a "dictionary of dictionaries" `_menu`:

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

static NSString *kLabel   = @"label";
static NSString *kAuthUrl = @"auth_url";

@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSDictionary *_menu;
    NSArray *_keys;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    _menu = @{
              @"FB": @{
                      kLabel:   @"Facebook",
                      kAuthUrl: @"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?",
                      },
              @"GG": @{
                      kLabel:   @"Google+",
                      kAuthUrl: @"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?",
                      },
              @"MR": @{
                      kLabel:   @"Mail.ru",
                      kAuthUrl: @"https://connect.mail.ru/oauth/authorize?",
                      },
              @"OK": @{
                      kLabel:   @"Odnoklassniki",
                      kAuthUrl: @"http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/oauth/authorize?",
                      },
              @"VK": @{
                      kLabel:   @"VKontakte",
                      kAuthUrl: @"http://oauth.vk.com/authorize?",
                      },
            };
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _keys.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *key = _keys[indexPath.row];
    NSString *label = _menu[key][kLabel];
    cell.textLabel.text = label;
    return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *key = _keys[indexPath.row];
        NSDictionary *dict = _menu[key];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:dict]; // XXX the error line
    }
}

@end
```

Finally in the [DetailViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/MyAuth/MyAuth/DetailViewController.m) I try to take the passed NSDictionary `dict` and load the URL in the `webView`:

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

static NSString *kLabel   = @"label";
static NSString *kAuthUrl = @"auth_url";

@interface DetailViewController ()
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

- (void)setDetailItem:(NSDictionary*)newDict
{
    if (_dict != newDict) {
        _dict = newDict;

        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    if (_dict) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_dict[kAuthUrl]];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [_webView loadRequest:request];
    }
}

@end
```

Unfortunately I get the compile-time error in Xcode:

> MasterViewController.m: No known instance method for selector 'setDetailItem:'

for this line:

```
    [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:dict];
```

Why does it happen?

The [destinationViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIStoryboardSegue/destinationViewController) property of UIStoryboardSegue class is declared as type `id`, shouldn't it accept any selectors?

Comment: It will accept any selector but the selector still need to be declared somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compile time error is because you have neither declared that selector in the `DetailViewController.h` file nor did you have declared any property of `NSDictionary` by the name of `*detailItem`.

When you have declare your property by

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *detailItem;
```

, the compiler would have generated a setter method automatically which you can override

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(NSDictionary*)detailItem{
}
```

If you are going to have your property as `dict`, try `-(void)setDict:(NSDictionary*)dict{}`

Check more about the properties in the Apple's documentations or go through a few links like [this](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/properties.html).

Comment: Yeah, `- (void)setDetailItem:(NSDictionary*)newDict;` missing from `DetailViewController.h`

Comment: Thanks! So the root cause has been me calling a "private" method :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, at the point where the compiler hits

```
[[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:dict];
```

it doesn't know of *any* class that declares `setDetailItem:`  If it finds an object declared as an `id` it will search *all* of its known declarations for a matching selector to use, if it finds none, it emits the error you are seeing.

You need to make sure that the header file for the class that declares the property (or method) `setDetailItem:` is imported into the `.m` file.  Then it will compile.